# How to implement ISampleGrabber to be used on Windows CE 7

Tags: c++, directshow, sample, frame-grab

I tried to reuse the code from here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28790/Creating-Custom-DirectShow-SampleGrabber-Filter-fo

To implement the SampleGrabber that I need to capture frames from a Camera on Windows CE 7.

The problem is compiling the solution breaks on CTransInPlaceFilter. It looks like it doesn't exist.

Is there any other solution for this. I do not require strictly SampleGrabber any other is good enough but need to be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have CTransInPlaceFilter you need to include Streams.h and link the base classes library (Strmbase.lib) which must be built beforehand. It's in the SDK, Samples\MultiMedia\DirectShow\BaseClasses.